# How to mark / tag / label forwarded and replied to messages in Gmail?

Tags: gmail, gmail-labels

When I forward a message or reply to a message in Gmail, the Gmail inbox does not show these messages as forwarded or replied to.

There is no indicator at all, so I can't tell if I have already forwarded or replied to a certain message, which is very important for me, especially when I need to handle with many business emails on a daily basis.

What I want to have, is the same indicator / marker for forwarded and replied to messages as the one in Outlook:

[image: Outlook 2003 Reply Indicator]

[image: Outlook 2003 Forward Indicator]

[image: Outlook 2010 Reply Indicator]

The only feature in Gmail which is somewhat close to what I'm trying to achieve, is the [conversation](http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=5900) counter, which doesn't necessarily indicate I have replied to a message:

[image: Gmail conversation counter]

I know the conversation view can be disabled, however it wouldn't solve my problem; while it will split conversations to single messages, I will still have to label every message I have forwarded or replied to, and since every message is on its own, I wouldn't be able to set a filter to detect messages I have replied to (which is possible in conversation view).

I have found [this Google Groups discussion](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/gmail/bCe4SjG3HOs/discussion) regarding the lack of this feature in Gmail. However, there is no solution for this problem at the moment, and it doesn't look like a similar feature will be added to Gmail anytime soon.

---

Any ideas on what can be done to achieve something similar to what I'm looking for?

Comment: The "me" in your conversation counter screen shot indicates that there's a message in the conversation that originated from you.

Comment: I know, but I want to know whether I have replied to the last message that was sent to me in the conversation. See my (edited) answer below.

Answer (score 5):

This is the best way I have found to make an automatic forwarded and replied to messages indicator / marker in Gmail - based on a filter (conversation view must be enabled):

1. Go to `Settings -> Labels` and create two new labels: `Replied` and
   `Forwarded`. You can also shorten their names to `RPL` and `FWD`. It
   doesn't matter what you label them, just as long as it has meaning
   to you.

   You can also colorize the labels as you want - e.g Green for `Replied` and Blue for `Forwarded`.
2. Go to `Settings -> Filters` and create a new filter with only
   one condition - **`From: me`**. Make sure you apply the label to your inbox.

   - You can also create two more filters for messages containing the words `Re:` and `Fwd:` in the subject, but some messages arrive with the word `Re:` in the subject, and some people delete the word `Re:` from the subject when they reply to a message.

**However**, this does not solve the problem entirely; for example, if I reply to a certain message, and the recipient replies back, then the conversation is still labeled as `Replied`. That's the reason conversations that include `(someone, me)` only indicate I have replied *at least* one time in the conversation.

If the conversation view is disabled - I won't have the problem mentioned above - but I won't be able to automatically mark / tag / label messages I have replied to, because my reply is not part of a conversation, and therefore I can't apply any generic filter to messages I have replied to.

Comment: What you could do, in addition to the above, is cc (or bcc) each message to `your.email+fwd@gmail.com` or `your.email+rpl@gmail.com`. Then create filters for messages from those addresses, which apply the `RPL` and `FWD` tags.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I do...

When I reply or forward the email I then archive the conversation. I do make sure that a filter added a label, or I added a label manually. When the conversation is archived it is no longer in the inbox. If another party responds to the email then Gmail brings the entire conversation back to the inbox. Thus starting the cycle over again.

If I have a need to check back with the recipient I either add a task, or leave the conversation in the inbox with a star.

Another approach is to use the Gmail labs Multiple Inboxes, you can then see all the recent conversations with a specific label. If you add is:starred to the search query you can limit it to only this conversations you starred.

Comment: Doesn't stuff in Gmail labs tend to *break*? I believe many people can't afford to let Labs play experiments with their inbox and corrupt it in the process.

Comment: The lab items I mentioned in this answer are still working 20 months later.